# ASP.NET Core.Http.HttpRequest does not contain definition for 'CreateResponse','RequestUri' and 'CreateErrorResponse'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert below code from ASP.Net MVC to ASP.Net Core MVC. But 'CreateResponse','RequestUri' and 'CreateErrorResponse' are missing in the Core MVC.

```
public HttpResponseMessage CallUserMappings()
    {
        try
        {
            //return response status as successfully created with  entity  
            var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            //Response message with requesturi for check purpose  
            msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString());
            return msg;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return response as bad request  with exception message.  
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoEXd.png)

Is there any alternative approach for these?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `Created` and `BadRequest`  methods? They are located in `ControllerBase`, which all controllers should inherit from.

Comment: Yes, I tried calling this in the controller and that inherit from 'ControllerBase'. But it is showing no definition.

Comment: What version of .NET core are you on?

Comment: I am using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 does have the `Created` and `BadRequest` methods in the `ControllerBase` class, as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Can you clarify what "showing no definition" means?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of the error in that place, can you check in the question

Comment: Your screenshot contains no mention of either the `Created` or `BadRequest` methods, which are the replacements for your old code.

Comment: Can you help how to replace the old code with those methods with the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an untested equivalent in .NET Core:

```
public IActionResult CallUserMappings()
{
    try
    { 
        return Created(Request.GetDisplayUrl(), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

To use the `Request.GetDisplayUrl()` method, you need to import the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` namespace.